# check_password_hash ever return False

Tags: mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login, werkzeug

I am creating a flask api with login auth but the check_password_hash ever return false and I get a error

in my app.py i'm trying this

```
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

@app.route("/signup", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def signup():
    if request.method == "POST":
        hashed_pw = generate_password_hash(request.form["password"], method="sha256")
        new_user = Users(username=request.form["username"], password=hashed_pw)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()

        return "You've registered successfully."

    return render_template("signup.html")

@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = Users.query.filter_by(username=request.form["username"]).first()

        if user and check_password_hash(user.password, request.form["password"]):
            session['username'] = user.username
            return "You are logged in"
        else:
            return "Your credentials are invalid, check and try again."

    return render_template("login.html")
```

when i print user.password and request.form["password"] it returns hashed

pass -> sha256$SSC4jjZIE3Wm6l7v$74e78b19ddfa3ad62963c93f34d9c6cd93b67e47b4e42e896a726d79
pass -> 1

Comment: Print `user.password` and `request.form["password"]` just to see if they look correct.

Comment: when i print user.password and request.form["password"] it returns

hashed pass -> sha256$SSC4jjZIE3Wm6l7v$74e78b19ddfa3ad62963c93f34d9c6cd93b67e47b4e42e896a726d79

pass -> 1

Comment: What are you using to hash the password?

Comment: from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

Comment: `pass -> 1` That doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure that request.form["password"] is returning the password that the user typed.

I don't know how you are hashing the password. Anyways a simple way to do it is using python passlib. it has no known weaknesses.

```
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
```

to save the hash:

```
hashed_password = sha256_crypt.hash("ThePassword")
```

to check the password:

```
ha256_crypt.verify("password from the form", hashed_password)
```

Comment: from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt Can't be imported it show me an error
 from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'passlib'

Comment: pip install passlib, or pip3 install passlib

Comment: thanks, it worked for me. but I still want to know why before it worked for me with check_password_hash but not now 

Comment: I don't understand why you would need to do any hashing yourself.  `user.password` is already hashed, and `check_password_hash()` hashes the candidate password for you.

Comment: hashed_password is saved in the database when the user registers. and ha256_crypt.verify is used to verify when user is logging in.